# How should I remove tiles and backer board from my bathroom?

Tags: tile, basement-refinishing, backer-board

I have a pink tiled bathroom and want to remove them.  The tiles come up fairly easy but some do not and the backer board is intact mostly. What is the best way to remove the tiles and backer board if I have to?  This is around a jetted tub and the tile job was not done by a professional.

Comment: Is the backerboard a concrete board variety or drywall?

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing the backer board, protect the tub (tape plastic over it and perhaps also use something like moving blankets or cardboard to pad it against impact) and use a crowbar and/or sledgehammer (with care not to go through the other side of the wall nor to damage the tub) to gain access for the crowbar to pry the backer-board off the studs. Or break it next to the studs, and then break what's left off the screws (if it was screwed in place), and then locking pliers to get the screws out.

If the backer board is not defective, and you are not removing the wall itself, consider the same sort of tub protection and using a wide, flat chisel to break off the stubborn tiles, followed by a "rubbing brick" to clean off the remaining thinset.

Comment: This is an excellent answer

Comment: I would not use a sledgehammer unless the whole wall was coming down.  Maybe you have a better touch with a sledgehammer but I have hit studs and both bounced a wall over a 1/4" and popped a stud right through drywall.

Answer (score 0):

Some tiles will pop right out via shattering if you wave a blow torch over them. Be sure you know what you are doing before attempting this.